# Determining which polygons only intersect once with the polygons of another shapefile

Tags: arcpy, county, redistricting

I have two shapefiles, one for counties and one for congressional districts. I need to determine which counties are in more than one congressional district. I would think I could use postgis and use some combination of ST_intersects and ST_touches, or ST_overlaps, unless there is an easy option in Arc or QGIS. What makes this more difficult is that I need to do this for 100 years back so the further back you go the less data there is, so for example, I have a county shapefile for 1970 that has a resolution of 1:250,000 and a congressional district shapefile for 1970 that has a resolution of 1:500,000, and I can't find shapefiles that match resolution, so how would I work around that problem as well. Just wondering if anybody has any pointers for either of those problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ArcPy, you could loop though your county features and use the shape of each as input to a select by location for congressional districts. Then you can use getCount_management to see how many districts are in that county. If there are more than 1, you can flag that county by updating a field.
The code could look something like this:

```
districts = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer('path/to/districts_shapefile', 'districts')
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('path/to/county_shapefile', ['SHAPE@', 'multi-district_field']) as counties:
  for county in counties:
    arcpy.SelectByLocation_management(districts, "INTERSECT", county[0])
    if int(arcpy.GetCount_management(districts).getOutput(0)) > 1:
      county[1] = "True"
      counties.updateRow(county)
```

this would populate "True" in a field of your counties table for each county that intersects more than one district.

Comment: This will work, however I think scripting should be avoided when possible. This can be done using simple intersect. Calculate frequency of countyID in output and bring it back to parent table using attribute join